# How to interpret Bansuri Scale reading on "Swar Meter"

Tags: scales, flute, woodwinds, indian-classical, bansuri

I downloaded "Swar Meter" and played `Sa` on my 23" Bansuri that says "A" scale

However, "Swar Meter" consistently measures between "A" and "A#"

I tried same exercise on my 24" Bansuri that says "A" scale and I get same result, i.e. "Swar Meter" consistently measures between "A" and "A#"

Which is it? Are both my flute "A" Scale as it is written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because we cannot produce a perfect note consistently (even after practicing for yeas). This is because of the blowing inconsistency, lip position hand position etc.. Don't worry. Keep practicing and try to see it is as nearer to A as possible. Moreover, your ears should get trained to match the Bansuri to the Tanpura. Initially, when the Note (swara) does not match and is off by a very narrow margin, you hear beats (small vibrations). What you need to practice is how to eliminate the beats by adjusting lip position and also constant blowing..  You may have to tilt the bansuri inwards or outwards depending on what you are producing (a bit higher or lower note).